# how to allow japanese text in text box which is not allowing special characters

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I have registration form with textbox fields, some of text fields are validated for not allowing special characters and I want to use japanese characters. But the textboxes which are not allowing special characters are also not allowing japanese text. so how to allow japanese language. I am using Regular Expression for validating textboxes.

My code is here:

```
private Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$");
private Regex phnRegex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");
private Regex nameRegex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z\ ]+$");
private Regex cmpnRegex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z\ \.\,\(\)]+$");
```

Comment: you don't need to escape `,() .` symbols inside character class.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Do you understand what do your regexes do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex:

```
\p{L}
```

matches all Letters, in any language. without Special characters.